# How to enable an Instant App in Unity without Google's SDK?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I read that to enable an Android build as an Instant App, you need to add `android:targetSandboxVersion="2"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I added this to `Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml`, but it is not getting included in my final APK:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:targetSandboxVersion="2">
  <application>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Or perhaps it's possible to achieve this with Gradle?

I don't want to use Google's Instant Play Unity SDK, I am trying to do it **manually**.

Any help is appreciated :)